# Error in makePage: unused argument (alist(div(HorizontalStack(makeCard(NULL, firstcard, size = 4, style = "max-height: 320px"))), ))

Tags: r, shiny, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

So I get this error and don't know how to solve this:

simsettings.R:

```
source("helperfunctions.R")


time_hours <- seq.int(0, 23)
time_minutes <- seq.int(0, 59)
bg_values <- seq.int(30, 200)

firstcard <- Stack(
    tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
    HorizontalStack(
        Label("Huidige tijd:"),
        Dropdown.shinyInput("hours_current", value = "-", options = c(time_hours)),
        Dropdown.shinyInput("minutes_current", value = "-", options = c(time_minutes))
    ),
    HorizontalStack(
        Label("Huidige BG:"),
        Dropdown.shinyInput("bg_current", value = "-", options = c(bg_values))
    )
)

simsettingspage <- tagList(
    makePage(
        t("Simulatie instellingen"),
        div(
            HorizontalStack(
                makeCard(NULL, firstcard, size = 4, style = "max-height: 320px")
            )
        ),
    )
)
```

My helperfunctions.R class:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(glue)
library(leaflet)
library(plotly)
library(sass)
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(shiny.router)

# Template functions
# ========================================================================

makeCard <- function(title, content, size = 12, style = "") {
  div(
    class = glue("card ms-depth-8 ms-sm{size} ms-xl{size}"),
    style = style,
    Stack(
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 5),
      Text(variant = "large", title, block = TRUE),
      content
    )
  )
}

makePage <- function(title) {
  tagList(
    div(
      class = "page-title",
      span(
        title,
        class = "ms-fontSize-32 ms-fontWeight-semibold",
        style = "color: #323130"
      ),
    ),
    # contents
  )
}

HorizontalStack <- function(...) {
  Stack(
    horizontal = TRUE,
    tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
    ...
  )
}

VerticalStack <- function(...) {
  Stack(
    vertical = TRUE,
    tokens = list(childrenGap = 10),
    ...
  )
}
```

mainbody.R (it takes all the different panels that will be visible on the mainbody:

```
source("simulationsettings.R")
source("assistent.R")
source("helperfunctions.R")

mainbody <- Stack(
    HorizontalStack(
        simulationsettings,
        assistent
    )
)
```

This mainbody is then connected to a router which is connected to app.R. I know this part works since it has always worked up untill I started making the Cards.

Answer (score 0):

I hopefully you've figured out the problem in the meanwhile. If not, I got a small comment (but I can't comment, since i do not have a high enough reputation).

I had a similar error, which was caused by an extra comma in the input parameters for a custom function.

```
getparams <- function(Input1 = input1, Input2 = input2, Input3 = input3){}
```

when calling:

```
getparams(input1, input2, input3,)
```

So it suggested another input parameter was expected, while there was none.
If the code you show is the actual code you used, the error might be caused by some extra, unused commas, for example in the taglists or in the custom functions.

Hope this helps!